# Line graph at SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, pivot

I have created SQL script PIVOT which generate data and I want to create line graph for it.

```
Year Jan Feb Mar Apr May -Dec
2012 00 00 00 00 50 20 
2013 116 113 182 144 50 435
2014 184 135 00 00 00 00
```

I am adding line chart with markers from SSRS charts, i am not able to create year as line graph, Y axis will show numbers, X axis will shows months. can somebody guide me in this regards?

thanks

Comment: To do this in a chart, realistically the data will need to be unpivoted, not pivoted; then you can just add `Year` and `Month` columns as **Category Groups** and your value column as the Series value.

Comment: I agree with @Preston. Your dataset should be Year, Month, Value.

Comment: @IanPreston thanks for your comment, when i export same data with same columns, i am able to do proper chart at MS Excel 2010, there it shows three series and it generate exact chart what i look for, it shows three lines with qty numbers for each year and at X Axis all months. Unfortunately i m not able to attache the image here..as this data come real time, i am finding it difficult to arrange with SSRS. In Dataset it will be one variable for year, and 12 variable for month, values for each is also available, but i can't sum months to make one variable, in that case it will not generate line

Comment: @RonSmith query i use part 1
'code'
SELECT [ISYear],
   isnull(Jan,0) as Jan, 
      isnull(Feb,0) as Feb,
      isnull(Mar,0) as Mar,
      isnull(Apr,0) as Apr,
      isnull(May,0) as May,
      isnull(Jun,0) as Jun,
      isnull(Jul,0) as Jul,
      isnull(Aug,0) as Aug,
      isnull(Sep,0) as Sep,
      isnull(Oct,0) as Oct,
      isnull(Nov,0) as Nov,
      isnull(Dec,0) as Dec
From (
SELECT  iid_item_code ItemCode, iid_issue_qty as IssuedQty, 
YEAR(iid_created_date) as [ISYear], 
LEFT(datename(Month,iid_created_date),3) as [ISSmonth]
From issue_inv_detail 
where iid_item_code = 'GEC0122'

Comment: @RonSmith query part 2 -



and YEAR(iid_created_date) >= '2012'
group by iid_item_code, iid_issue_qty,iid_created_date
)as INVISS
PIVOT
(
  SUM(IssuedQty)
  FOR [ISSmonth] IN  (Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec)
)as PVT

Comment: @bluefeet      hello guys.. please help me unpivot and re-pivot

Comment: See my answer below. The query results are unpivoted and I included how to set up the SSRS chart.

Answer (score 2):

You should simply group your IssuedQty values by Year and Month like this:

```
-- load test data
    declare @issue_inv_detail table(iid_item_code int identity(1,1),iid_issue_qty int,iid_created_date datetime)
    while (select count(*) from @issue_inv_detail) < 1000
        begin
            insert into @issue_inv_detail(iid_issue_qty,iid_created_date)
                values
                    (round(rand()*10,0),dateadd(day,round(rand()*765,0),'20120101'))
        end

-- return @issue_inv_detail grouped by Year,Month
    select
        year(iid_created_date) ISYear,
        month(iid_created_date) ISMonth,
        sum(iid_issue_qty) ISQty
    from @issue_inv_detail
    group by
        year(iid_created_date),
        month(iid_created_date)
    order by
        year(iid_created_date),
        month(iid_created_date)
```

Then set your SSRS Chart values:

- Value: ISQty
- Category Group: ISMonth
- Series Group: ISYear